# Connect postcode to administrative boundry level

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, postcode

In OSM I would like depict a certain area ("working area"). Using the following I can specify a certain area around a certain city:

```
[out:json][timeout:800];
{{geocodeArea:Netherlands}}->.searchArea;
{{radius=40000}}
(
  node["admin_level"="8"](area.searchArea)(around:{{radius}}, {{geocodeCoords:Oirschot}});  
  relation["admin_level"="8"](area.searchArea)(around:{{radius}}, {{geocodeCoords:Oirschot}});
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

However the radius does not deliver the required area. An alternative is to use the postal code, which might look like:

```
/*
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Eindhoven” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Eindhoven}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["addr:postcode"~"^56"](area.searchArea);
  way["addr:postcode"~"^56"](area.searchArea);
  relation["addr:postcode"~"^56"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I am struggling in finding the administrative border of the latter result, such that I can improve the first code snippet to specify the cities based on a list of postalcodes.

Which direction I should look for?

Comment: Postal codes are linear or even point features. You cannot reliably convert them to polygon without error.

Comment: Maybe I was not complete enough: I would like to check if the given postalcodes are within a certain admin level and if so show the admin level (such that I can remove the radius approach in the first example).
There's an example with banks & police stations (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Banks_far_away_from_police_stations), but I can not find how to check if a certain postcode is within a certain administrative boundry.

Comment: Postcodes often cross administrative boundaries.

Comment: So, than it might be possible to highlight both administrative boundaries. So basicaly, check if a postalcode belongs to an administrative boundry and if so highlight the administrative boundry.